# nginx Увеличить время ожидания ответа для определенного урла

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Есть сервер на NGINX. На сайте сделано API. При запросе по определенному url выдается список товаров в формате json. Если ставлю небольшое количество товаров, то всё нормально, если ставлю большое число - получаю 50х ошибку. Сам запрос отрабатывается в течении где-то 10 секунд. На старом сервере тоже был NGINX, работало без проблем....  но уже не помню, какие там были настройки.

Подскажите, какой параметр отвечает за время ожидания ответа от сервера, и как его можно установить только для определеного урла.

Установил `fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;` в настройках nginx не помогает (или не работает, не знаю как проверить)

Comment: Конфиг покажите

Answer (score 1):

У меня вот так настроено

```
    location /long_responce {
       proxy_connect_timeout 300;
       proxy_send_timeout    300;
       proxy_read_timeout    300;
    }
```